# Accessing the controls in a StartNavigationTemplate within a Wizard

Tags: asp.net, wizard

wizard.FindControl does not find the control.

How do I access it so, for example, I can change the text on a button? I'm using a 3rd party source for the button text so cannot use Globalization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you could try something like this :

Button btnNext = (Button)MyWizard.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID$StartNextButton");

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to find the controls directly using find control. But what you can do is create your own Template for the navigation templates (you will need to inherit from iTemplate). There are 3 of these startNavigationTemplate,StepNavigationTemplate and finish navigation template. Start template will display for the wizard steps which have stepType set as Start etc. Worth noting that you can set the template for all of the templates etc.

good article on wizard control is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx